# New message without refreshing/Clicking the page/link - PHP

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, messagebox

I'm working on messaging module

1) How can i show a new message, without clicling on the inbox everytime
something like facebook ??

when you message to a friend...you dont need to refresh...messages keeps coming in ??

any help

thanq

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. Perhaps you should start with [basic Ajax/Comet concepts](http://blog.leahculver.com/2009/07/a-is-for-ajax-and-c-is-for-comet.html).

Comment: thanq, never got know abt comet

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify your question. In the comments below you tell that you already have the AJAX part down but that you just need te adapt it some more.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use Push technology... please have a look at this website...http://z-push.sourceforge.net/soswp/ this is for mobile... you may need to figure it out how to make it work for web...

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a javascript timer that makes a polled request against the server every n seconds.

Comment: yeah, i'm using the timer at the moment
self.setInterval(function,time);
calling the ajax file and showing the messages...
but, when the problem comes with pagination

Comment: Your ajax callback logic needs to update the values you're holding for paging, but we'd need to see your paging and callback js code to help with that

Comment: if a user is another page(i mean he is second page of messages) and once the javascript timer hits...i'm being taken to first page...how can i solve this ??

Comment: One way would be like twitter.... let the user know that there are x new messages without actually displaying the messages themselves until the user goes back to the first page... though twitter also provides the "there are x new messages" text as a link to request refreshing back to the first page

Comment: this is awesome, i can do this for the moment
how come facebook implemented messaging :-P

Comment: yeah done and implemented successfully without any problems
i was taking the pagination number in hidden variable and checking if that page number is greater than 1 then i'm not taking him to home page...its working fine now, thanks a lot

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, then "accept" it by clicking on the tick symbol alongside, so that other people can see that it's resolved